# How to UPDATE from SELECT result where condition is ROWNUM?

Tags: oracle, sql-update, rownum

I am having some problem creating update query based on select query with ROWNUM as WHERE condition.

I did experiments with these queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUM, RVT.* FROM RVT)
WHERE RVT_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

This works, but

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT ROWNUM, RVT.* FROM RVT)  AS TEMP_TABLE1
WHERE TEMP_TABLE1.RVT_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

doesn't work.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
UPDATE REVIEW_T  
SET RVT_RATING = 1 
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM, RVT.* FROM RVT )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Which does not work. Also,

```
UPDATE REVIEW_T  
SET RVT_RATING = 1 
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM, RVT.* FROM RVT) AS TEMP_TABLE
WHERE TEMP_TABLE.ROWNUM = 1;
```

doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. Sample data and desired results, as tabular text would help in that regard. Also, please define *not working*; are you getting errors, wrong results, ...?

Comment: I have a table with 600 rows of data. This table does not have simple index primary key. It has a primary key made by 3 foreign keys. I am trying to build a java servlet that can loop i = 1 to 600 that will update rows.

Comment: Simply speaking, I want to create 'index' 1,2,3,....600 for the all rows of one of my existing table. And I want to use that index to update all rows one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create 'index' 1,2,3,....600 for the all rows of one of my existing table

If that's so, then

```
UPDATE REVIEW_T SET RVT_RATING = rownum;
```